# Why is `1.0 / 0` used instead of `Float::INFINITY`?

Tags: ruby, infinity

I read code of the gem [rom](https://github.com/rom-rb/rom), particularly its submodule [rom-relation](https://github.com/rom-rb/rom-relation) writen by known good ruby developers. In [`rom-relation/lib/rom-relation.rb`](https://github.com/rom-rb/rom-relation/blob/master/lib/rom-relation.rb), we can read:

```
#Represent a positive, infinitely large Float number
Infinity  = 1.0 / 0
```

but I didn't see any use of `Float::INFINITY`.

In irb, I tried:

```
> 1.0/0 == Float::INFINITY
=> true
```

- Why not use `Float::INFINITY`?
- `Infinity` starts with an uppercase which is a constant, but why not `INFINITY`? (I.e., what convention is used here?)

Comment: `INFINITY` starts with an uppercase.

Comment: If I say my mother language is not english and so I don't master all english language, am I forgiven ?

Comment: Why so many down and close votes? It's a reasonable question.

Comment: @Stefan: Well, it's hard to give an objective, definitive answer - no-one other than the author can really say why they've done something. That may explain the close votes.

Answer (score 8):

Jon already said that `Float::INFINITY` was introduced in Ruby 1.9.2. Therefore, if ROM used this constant, it would require Ruby 1.9.2.

`1.0/0` on the other hand works for every Ruby version.

However, you can of course use `Float::INFINITY` in your code:

```
ROM::Infinity == Float::INFINITY
#=> true
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the code was written before `Float::INFINITY` was introduced? It looks to me like it was introduced in Ruby 1.9.2: [1.9.1 docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.1/Float.html), [1.9.2 docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Float.html). A quick trawl around the web suggests that Ruby was introduced in August 2010. Even though the specific file you're looking at is very new, I suspect the code was copied from somewhere old.

(I can't comment on the naming. Looking at the context, there's a mixture there already.)

Comment: With git  I can see that the part of code is 
Author: Piotr Solnica <piotr.solnica@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Jun 4 19:34:46 2013 +0200
I can't believe it was wrote before August 2010.

Comment: @Hettomei: As I said in the answer, I suspect it was *copied* from somewhere old. Why can you not believe that that line was first written before August 2010? Ruby's been around a long time, and people often copy bits of code from one place to another.

Comment: It could be that the code tries to remain backwards compatible, or that the author was not *aware* that `Float::INFINITY` was added, and stuck to a trick he knew.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Indeed - the latter seems more likely to me, unless Ruby pre-1.9.2 is still common in the wild.

Comment: Not sure about the Ruby ecosystem, but many Python library devs still support Python 2.6; 2.7 came out in July 2010. Many LTS Linux distros bundle 2.6 still. Presumably Ruby faces the same landscape, and it could well be that per-1.9.2 support still makes sense.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Quite possibly. This is why it's not a great question - we can't really tell whether that's the reason, even though it definitely *could* be.

Comment: I "can't believe" because, 'Rom' is a new gem designed to replace Datamapper, furthermore, I see really good presentation from "piotr solnica" so i naively thought this code was wrote for really good reason. Backwards compatibility, why not but : a .ruby-version specify 1.9.3, and 'Infinity' is not use in the 4 modules. Maybe you are right, I should ask directly to the author.

Comment: I dont see why Stefan gets 6 upvotes and Jon 0, although Stefan only repeated Jon's answer an hour later... ?